# How do I turn off hover for this <li>?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to turn off the hover for the current page in a navigation menu.

```css
div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 40px;
}
.nav li {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 40px;
}
li.current {
  background-color: #424242
}
li.current:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #737373;
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">Home</li>
    <li><a href="null">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="null">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="null">Gallery</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/swordams/jk6z5aqj/

I want the `li` for home to stay dark and not change on hover. I've tried setting the hover background color to "inherit", but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I rushed to the submit button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution by j08691 but ultimately, the problem with your css is that  `.nav li:hover` is more specific than `li.current:hover`. Tacking a `.nav` will do the trick.

```
.nav li.current:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! j08691's answer worked, but this answer is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```
.nav li:hover:not(.current) {
    background-color: #737373;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6hp75qce/)**

Answer (score 0):

just make the active/current li background color important

```
li.current {
    background-color: #424242 !important;
}
```